# how to Restrict char array to take only a's and b's from string in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a program which takes the string and converts it into char array. I want to create regular expression without regex library which accepts all strings of a's and b's which has `aa` somewhere.

My code below is working fine but the only problem is that it accepts chars other than a's and b's as well e.g it accepts `baabss` as well.
Can you help to correct the code so that it rejects the string in that case ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input_string;
    char char_string[20];
    int counter=0;

    cout << "type in some input text:$" << endl;
    cin >> input_string;

    strcpy(char_string, input_string.c_str());

    for (int i = 0;  i < sizeof(input_string); i++)
    {
        if(char_string[i]=='a' || char_string[i]=='b'){
            switch(char_string[i])
            {
             case 'a' :
                 counter++;
                 break;              
             case 'b' :
                 if(counter==1){
                     counter=0;
                 }               
                 break;
            }
         }
     }

     if(counter==2){
        cout << "String accepted" << endl;
     }
     else{
        cout << "String not accepted" << endl;
     }
     std::cin.get();
     system ("PAUSE");   
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert to a character array? The `operator[]` will work with `std::string`.

Comment: I did that to match each character with switch statement

Comment: @Inam the problem is that you don't reject the string if it has a foreign char

Comment: @JakeFreeman... thank you sir i get it now i skipped the else part now its working

Comment: @Inam could you upvote my comment?

Comment: @JakeFreeman  It's not sufficient:  the string `baaab`  gets rejected as well.  Same for a string that would be made of a lot of b and have two consecutive a only after the `sizeof(string)`  chars (sizeof being the fixed size of its argument)

Comment: @Christophe `baab` should be rejected

Comment: @JakeFreeman "*accepts all strings of a's and b's which has aa somewhere*" : baab and baaab both corresponds to that definition.

Comment: @Christophe both are acceptable if you make it `if(counter >= 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems with invalid chars**

In your loop body, you have to reject the chars that are neither a nor b.  So you have to complete

```
   if(char_string[i]=='a' || char_string[i]=='b'){
       ...
   }
```

with an `else` clause.  For example:

```
   else {
       counter=0;   // reset the counter so that the final check will fail
       break;       // exit the for loop
   }
```

**Problems that you have not detected so far**

A first problem is that `sizeof(input_string)` doesn't return what you expect !  Use `input_string.size()` instead.

Then the program will fail to accept `baaab`, because it will cause the loop to end with counter being 3.  Therefore you have to change your final check into:

```
 if(counter>=2){  // instead of ==
```

**Oops !**

Finally if you'd have a user input of more than 19 characters, your program would have undefined behavior, because the `strcpy()` would copy more chars than there is place in the array, thus causing memory corruption.    Strategies that you could use to correct this issue:

1. limit the size of the accepted user input using [`<iomanip>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/) (e.g.      `cin >> setw(19) >>input_string;`
2. limit the size of the copy using `strncat()` and inform the user if the input was truncated.  You must then also ensure that the loop does not go beyond the truncated size.
3. You could directly access the original chars in `input_string` without doing any copy.   Or if you prefer, you can remplace the char array with a vector that would get initialized from the string:     `vector<char>char_string(input_string.begin(), input_string.end());`

[Online demo of option 3](https://ideone.com/owptaP)

Comment: christphe... Thank you sir I get it now it is working fine ...you are great